# Fetching annotations field from Method class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to fetch the annotations field from Method class in Android Sdk 19 and jdk 1.7. But the code below is throwing NoSuchFieldException. But I could find the exact field in Method.java file.

```
Field field = Method.class.getDeclaredField("annotations");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the field cause it's `private`, in order to get around it you have to make it accessible first:

```
    Field f = Method.class.getDeclaredField("annotations"); 
    f.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println("f = " + f);
```

Comment: If you see the Method.java file , "annotations" is a byte[] type field. I'm confused why I'm unable to fetch it. To be precise I'm trying a hack, trying to get this field and update annotation of a method during run-time.   Method.class.getAnnotations() will only let you know the list of  Annotations and not update them.

Comment: @1987frank my bad - I thought you're trying to get the annotations of the class. You can't get the field because it's `private`. But you can get around it - see updated answer.

Comment: I don't think this is related to the issue you mentioned. The exception is thrown at the line "Field f= Method.class.getDeclaredField("annotations");".

Comment: @1987frank I ran it both with Java7 and Java8 and both printed: `"f = private byte[] java.lang.reflect.Method.annotations"`. If you're referring to `java.lang.reflect.Method` I don't believe that you should see a different output in Android env. Try to run with a debugger and see why it fails (I'm curious as well!)